# Format keys in Element API plugin

Tags: datetime, plugin-elementapi

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'news',
    'date' => craft()->request->getPost('date')
],
```

How to make that worked like this:

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'news',
    'date->format("Y-m-d")' => craft()->request->getPost('date')
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$postDate = craft()->request->getPost('date');
$nextDay = new DateTime($postDate);    
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'news',
    'date' => 'and,>='.$postDate.',<'.$nextDay->modify('+1 days')->format("Y-m-d"),
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work just for selecting a "day".

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'news',
    'customDateFieldHandle' => ['and', '>='.DateTime::createFromString(craft()->request->getPost('date'))->format("Y-m-d").' 00:00:00', '<='.$DateTime::createFromString(craft()->request->getPost('date'))->format("Y-m-d").' 23:59:59')];
],
```

Comment: you need to format the key and not the value

Comment: I'm not following... why?

Comment: I need entries certain with days, "date" this is date field and returns the date and time, and I need only a day

Comment: So you're searching against postDate?  Or a custom Date field?

Comment: is custom field

Comment: Updated answer.